# Keep all original constraint layout dimensions when keyboard moves EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `EditText` that looks like this when it is inactive:

[image]

When the `EditText` is active it changes to this:

[image]

As you can see it trims the background color above and below it. I want to keep it so nothing changes when the keyboard is active.

I tried adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` for the activity in the manifest but this changes nothing and it just looks like the image above. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan` gets it half right by keeping the background above but removing the border below, like so:

[image]

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustRezise"` hides is completely.

The `EditText` resides in a nested constraint layout. Here is the relevant `xml` for that:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_letter_entry"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_letters"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/et_padding_left_right"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/et_padding_left_right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2Container"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1Container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2Container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1Container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I make it so it doesn't change whether the keyboard is active or not?

Comment: Technically, `adjustPan` is not removing the bottom border and affecting your layout as `adjustResize` does, it is shifting your `EditText` to just above the keyboard so that it's visible. You can try wrapping your layout in a `scrollview` and scroll it to a certain position(50px below EditText) when keyboard appears.

Comment: I see., thanks for the suggestion I'll consider it if no other ways are suggested.

Comment: If you want to keep that margin between editText and your layout the easies way would be to add MarginTop and MarginBottom.